# How to cache google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine

Is it possible to cache Google Apps Engine for my static content; so far the only thing i have done with it is follow these directions to store my files http://www.digitalistic.com/2008/06/09/10-easy-steps-to-use-google-app-engine-as-your-own-cdn/
however in an effort to improve my end user experience i need a way to be able to cache all that content (mostly banners/images) for my users

is there a friendly guide for doing this for someone not so keen with python?

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: "_How to cache google app engine_" you should must check your heading seriously :D

Comment: i am sorry, english is my third language and I am not so good at expressing what I mean, what I need to do is to cache all the requests made by my website to Google App engine which I now use as CDN, how to  better reword this idea?

Comment: The browsers are making direct requests to the App Engine right? So each browser will query the data once and then use cached copy. What is the actual problem?

Comment: yes i had believe so as well, however it does not say it is cached copy when i use this tool for testing  http://www.webpagetest.org/result/120605_EJ_7AF/1/performance_optimization/#cache_static_content, all the ones called from the cdn say it expires in 10 minutes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you followed the instructions for configuring static handlers [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Static_File_Handlers).? You can configure the cache expiration for you static data and AppEngine will serve the files with the headers configured correctly.

Comment: hi stuart, this looks like the answer! I assume this goes into the app.yaml file?

Comment: yes this was the answer! webtest now shows up.thanks very much for your help, for anyone else that would need this, simply follow the guide above then use stuarts helpful suggestion!